# Java access DataBase connection

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I want to learn how to connect DB with java. I write following code for that:

```
package login;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Class.forName("sun.odbc.jdbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Test");

            Statement s = c.createStatement();

            String sql = "select * from Table1";

            ResultSet result = s.executeQuery(sql);

            while (result.next()) {
                System.out.println("\n" + result.getString(1) + "\t" + result.getString(2));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception generated:" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

but I get exception:

run:

> exception generated:sun.odbc.jdbc.JdbcOdbcDriver BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   (total time: 0 seconds)

I cerated database named **exp.accdb**. How I get solve this problem?

Comment: place an ``e.printStackTrace();`` inside the catch block please and take a look at the output.

Comment: What database do you use? MSSQL?, Oracle? MySql?

Comment: And what is your Java version?

Comment: can you share a bit of the exception log

Comment: The JDBC-ODBC bridge driver is not available if you're using JDK8.  It's been removed.  A better idea would be to use the Derby database bundled in the JDK with its driver class.  Do yourself a favor - go through the JDBC tutorial and learn about PreparedStatement.  Your example code isn't a good way to go.

Comment: i use MS Access DB

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to put in the database credentials, i.e. the hostname, username and password? 
For instance: 
 `c = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);`

You can check if it is connected during debugging by doing this as well:

```
if (c != null) {
   System.out.println("Connection established");
}
```

Comment: But, I use MS Access DB. so.... can you please tell me what is host name,username and password. I never set username & password in My Access Database